# CSV file. contain 2 different values in a row. How to separate them?

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, opencsv, csvhelper, read.csv

I have a file from mass spectrum(chemistry). In that file there are 2 different values for each axis like x and y. but both of them are in same row. so how to separate them.
150-2000 m/z,  123,53,54,23,35,56,68,89,90,etc
I know i can separate the values by comma into column but how to change the value 150-2000 into numbers and separate column like that
150
151
152
153
.
.
.
.
.
1999
2000

Thankx in advance

There are 2 different set of values in a row from a CSV file and I want to separate them into different columns. And one of the file is in 150-2000 range so how to convert it into simple numbers.

Comment: `first, second = row.split("-")`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Convert` in a `ClassMap` to convert the first column into your `x` and `y` values.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("150-2000 m/z,123"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().Dump();
    }
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    FooMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.X).Convert(args =>
        {
            var value = args.Row.GetField(0);
            var beforeDash = value.Split("-")[0];
            
            var canParse = int.TryParse(beforeDash, out int result);
            
            if (canParse)
            {
                return result;
            } 
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        });
        Map(m => m.Y).Convert(args =>
        {
            var value = args.Row.GetField(0);
            var afterDash = value.Split("-")[1];
            var beforeSpace = afterDash.Split(" ")[0];

            var canParse = int.TryParse(beforeSpace, out int result);

            if (canParse)
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        });
        Map(m => m.AnotherNumber).Index(1);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int AnotherNumber { get; set; }
}
```